# How do I change the graphics settings after the initial launch of the game?

Tags: pc, batman-arkham-city

The game gives me the option to adjust graphics settings the first time it's installed. However, when launching the game the second time, it goes straight into the game instead of giving me the 'launcher' so that I can change the settings again.

How do I get back to the screen where I can change the graphics options again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to the directory where you installed the game and enter the `Binaries\Win32` directory, run the executable `bmlauncher.exe`.

The default location is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\CapsuleGames\Batham Arkham City - PC\Batman - Arkham City\Binaries\Win32`

on 64bit windows, I suppose on 32 bit it would be

`C:\Program Files\CapsuleGames\Batham Arkham City - PC\Batman - Arkham City\Binaries\Win32`

[Source](http://community.batmanarkhamcity.com/forums/showthread.php/10965-How-to-change-graphical-settings-PC-version.)

Comment: Nice. It's actually installed under C:\Program Files (x86)\WB Games\Batman Arkham City\Binaries\Win32 . I just followed the general instructions otherwise and found the executable. It's strange that we need to go to this length to change graphics settings.

Comment: My folder says that the Win32 folder is empty. Any clues?

Comment: Matthew, do a Windows search for the file. We have no access to your computer, giving only one clue is not going to help us.

Comment: For some of us, launching bmlauncher doesn't do anything.. it's on the processes list but nothing on the UI shows up.
Problem since I played the game in windowed mode yesterday and now, it's in the wrong resolution :(

Comment: @JAnderton I would try finding the settings file and moving it so that it resets to the default settings.

Answer (score 5):

Steam gives you a way to launch the configuration program. Just right-click on **Batman: Arkham City™** in your Steam Library and choose the "Configure PC Options" menu item that appears.

Comment: Mine's not the Steam version. It's a box I bought from a retail shop, but your advice is definitely useful for Steam users.

Comment: I don't se this option on my Steam client (Arkham City GOTY)